# Animation of view in direction of swipe?

Tags: android, gesture-recognition

[image]

Currently I have managed to do the above, swiping in each of the three areas will being an XML animation to travel in that direction until I leaves the screen, this is however:

1. Pre defined route, it will go perfectly straight regardless of where the finger was swiped
2. There is swipe dead zones between the middle and side swipe areas.

I'm looking for a way to improve the swipe detection by following the actual swipe direction and also make the motion more realistic?

```
public abstract class OnUpDownGestureListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private Context context;

    private final GestureDetector gdt = new GestureDetector(this.context, new GestureListener());

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
        gdt.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            click();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

            float x1 = e1.getX();
            float y1 = e1.getY();

            float x2 = e2.getX();
            float y2 = e2.getY();

            if (y1 - y2 > 120 && Math.abs(velocityY) > 200) {
                onBottomToTop(); // Bottom to top
            } else if (y2 - y1 > 120 && Math.abs(velocityY) > 200) {
                return false; // Top to bottom
            }

            /**
             * bottom right to left top
             */
            if (x1 - x2 > 120 && x1 > x2 && y1 - y2 > 120 && y1 > y2) {
                onBottomRightToLeftTop();

            }
            /**
             * left top corner to right
             */
            else if (x2 - x1 > 120 && x2 > x1 && y2 - y1 > 120 && y2 > y1) {
                // onTopLeftToBottomRight();
            }
            /**
             * left bottom corner to right up
             */
            else if (x2 - x1 > 120 && x2 > x1 && y1 - y2 > 120 && y1 > y2) {
                onBottomLeftToRightTop();
            }

            /**
             * Right corner to left bottom down
             */
            else if (x1 > x2 && y2 > y1) {
                onTopRightToBottomLeft();
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public abstract void click();

    public abstract void onBottomRightToLeftTop();

    public abstract void onTopLeftToBottomRight();

    public abstract void onTopRightToBottomLeft();

    public abstract void onBottomLeftToRightTop();

    public abstract void onBottomToTop();

}
```

Comment: when you have a details of fling then you can get all the details to animate, angle speed x, y etc. so why do you want to limit it to those animations to certain "tunnels" - do you think it can be only done via XML animation? and also because it is quite old - can you also post any update on how you resolved/progressed with the issue.

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela That was my thinking unfortunately i was unable to find a way to animate the view along said coordinates without pre setting the animation depending on whether it's in one of those tunnels!

Comment: Google it? [This](http://android-er.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/implament-animation-using-java-code.html) could help a bit and [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/10/android-leaf-fall-like-animation-using.html):)

Comment: The first link seems to be exactly what im doing already, i'll look into the second.